# Any methods in place to detect when focus is lost on a jfreechart plot/chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

this is hopefully going to be a simple one on a friday afternoon. I have a plot/jfreechart and i add a marker and change it based on the x,y location. The question i have is, is there anyway to tell when the jfreechart in quesition looses foscus. i.e the mouse has been moved from the jfreechart/plot on to another Jcomponent?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I imagine to do such a thing would be to add a listener to the chart, Either a MouseListener or FocusListener as these record 'live' events such as mouse movements or focus changes.  I don't know how compatible these options are with your chart but these are likely to be your best (and possibly) only options.  I would look into whether you are able top incorporate these into your program onto your chart and go from there.

Good Luck!